# FHIR - Consent Resource - Giving Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.ComplexTypeReader error

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am not a techie but have assumed some responsibilities in someone's absence.

Trying to push below Consent FHIR Resource:

```
<Consent xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <id value="123" />
  <status value="inactive" />
  <scope>
    <coding>
      <system value="http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/consentscope" />
      <code value="patient-privacy" />
    </coding>
  </scope>
  <category>
    <coding>
      <system value="http://loinc.org" />
      <code value="59284-0" />
    </coding>
  </category>
  <patient>
    <reference value="Patient/41" />
    <display value="John Stifiles" />
  </patient>
  <policyRule>
    <coding>
      <system value="http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/consentpolicycodes" />
      <code value="cric" />
    </coding>
  </policyRule>
  <provision>
    <type value="deny" />
    <period>
      <start value="2021-09-27" />
      <end value="2021-09-27" />
    </period>
  </provision>
</Consent>
```

This is passed with no errors from inferno.healthit.gov/validator/ but when I run through my integrator (it hits HL7 validator), I get a variety of errors - Encountered unknown member 'Scope' or  Encountered unknown member 'Patient', etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Consent resource that conforms to FHIR version R4. Inferno runs FHIR R4 as well, so that works.

However, if you try and validate this resource against FHIR STU3, you will get the errors you mentioned, since the Consent resource structure significantly changed from STU3 to R4. Please check your integrator and make sure it runs FHIR R4 as well.

Comment: Thanks very much, Mirjam Baltus for your response. We are set up at R4 version. All other resources are good on R4 validation but just to be sure there wasnt anything wrong with Consent resource, I changed the structure to comply with STU3 validations and this gave me this error - Encountered element 'meta' from unsupported namespace '' (at path 'line 1, pos 2')| Stack :    at Hl7.Fhir.Serialization.ElementNavFhirReader.verifyXmlSpecificDetails(IElementNavigator child). Any further suggestions please?

Comment: And I dont think, that's a plausible scenario that all other resoruces are set up at R4 except for just one resource. If we assume it's an R4 validation happening, can you please suggest what should be done?

Comment: The message you now get comes from not listing the namespace on an XML resource. It has to start with: <Consent xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">.
I would not assume you're running R4, because some resource types like Patient are similar enough to pass both STU3 and R4 validation. First check what happens if you add the namespace.

Comment: Hello Mirjam, to reply to your question, I had to post another answer since I thought of pasting the entire resource and this comment couldn't take that many characters. Cam you please help? Thanks a googol!